# ¿Cómo puedo redondear números enteros en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Necesito que cuando el resultado de la función sea un número entero, como por ejemplo, 19.986, se redondee a 20.000 directamente.

He probado con Math.round() y también con toFixed() pero solo sirven para redondear números decimales.

```
function PreciodeVenta(costo, porcentaje){
    let PreciodeVenta= ((costo / (100 - porcentaje))*100);
    return [Math.round(PreciodeVenta), Math.round(PreciodeVenta-costo)]
```

Comment: Prueba con [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil).

Comment: Habría que ver otros casos, es decir, que pasa si es 987, o 12433, o 17844, cual sería el criterio de redondeo en cada uno?

Comment: Siguiendo los estándares de redondeo, deberían de redondearse al entero más próximo los números que tengan el primer decimal mayor o igual a `.5`. Sin embargo, esto es decisión del OP, el cual debe [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/599669/edit) su publicación para aclarar esto.

Comment: Adhiero, creo que tendría sentido... Solo para aclarar el mensaje de arriba, podría ser un redondeo por ejemplo de 1000 en 1000 o 500 en 500 o 0 o .5. Ejemplos: 18.956 podría redondear a 19.000 o a 20.000 o 18.280 podría redondear a 18.000, a 18.500 o también a 19.000.. Lo mismo podría ser en números mayores o menores, ej: 740 redondea a 500, a 800 o a 1000?

Comment: @LuisS.Romero Normalemente cuando se redondea se busca quitarle los decimales, pero para tomar en cuenta los decimales en tu calculos puedes ver si son mayores o igual a .5 si es asi se redondea para arriba, de lo contrario para abajo. Pero un redondeo nunca puede ser esto: 0.5 -> 2. o es 0 si no te interesa tomar en cuenta los decimales o 1(En el caso de la pregunta)

Comment: @RodrigoRamírez Creo que la pregunta esta bien asi : )

Comment: Creo que el OP se refiere a los números en milésimas... Esperaré a que adjunte más detalles y aclaraciones :-)...

Comment: @DanielBriceño, considero que lo peor es dar por sentado algo porque "usualmente se hace así" en especial sabiendo que a veces se  pregunta por casos puntuales que pueden ir desde un proyecto real hasta una propuesta quizás  académica con resultados fuera de "lo general". Cuando se hace una pregunta se debe dar información clara, código y casos de ejemplo suficientes para entender la idea y realizar pruebas. De otra forma eso puede significar tiempo desperdiciado de otras personas que con la mejor intención intentan ayudar. 
Por tal motivo sugiero que si no va a sumar, al menos no reste.

Comment: ª. @LuisS.Romero No leí bien la pregunta y pense que era redondear numeros decimales por el punto que puso el usuario, pero releo y ya entiendo porque se le busca la 5 patas al gato(como o que criterios necesitas para redondear un numero entero). Aunque creo que con solo decir que "no se está redondeando decimales sino entero", sería la forma mas fácil de hacerme entender que no se está trabajando con decimales.

Answer (score 2):

Digamos que necesitas dejar en el número cerrado más próximo, esto se puede hacer simplemente con `toPrecision` y luego multiplicar por `1`

Ejemplo:

```js
const redondea = num => num.toPrecision(1) * 1;

console.log(redondea(9));
console.log(redondea(16));
console.log(redondea(166));
console.log(redondea(19986));
```

`toPrecision` convierte al número en formato exponencial, al multiplicar `*1` cambiamos el formato a número nuevamente. Por lo que cualquier método que realice lo mismo tambien funciona. Ejemplo:

```js
const redondea1 = num => num.toPrecision(1) * 1;
const redondea2 = num => Number(num.toPrecision(1));
const redondea3 = num => num.toPrecision(1) - 0;


console.log(redondea1(19986));
console.log(redondea2(19986));
console.log(redondea3(19986));
```

Comment: Muy buena, aunque usaria `Number.parseInt()` para convertir a entero.

Comment: @eventHandler Hola, gracias por tu comentario. `parseInt` no funciona para este caso, porque esta función toma el formato exponencial como `string`  que es uno de los tantos errores que tiene esta función. Luego el siguiente error que tiene es que transforma los string a número de izquierda a derecha hasta que encuentra un carácter "no convertible", por ejemplo `parseInt(23ABCD)` lo convierte a `23`, y el en caso de formato exponencial `2e+2` lo convierte a `2` (por el motivo antes señalado). Por esto casi siempre conviene usar `Number(x)` para transformar.

Comment: Puedes hacer la pruena facilmente escribiendo en la consola `Number("2e+2")` y luego `Number.parseInt("2e+2")`, dan resultados distintos

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo!

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo más que una respuesta, es un punto de partida, tu sabrás como adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

```js
function redondear( valor ) {
       // convierto el número a string
    let valorComoTexto = valor.toString();       

       // tomo la longitud
    let longitud = valorComoTexto.length;

       // guardo los dos números más significativos
    let cabeza = valorComoTexto.substring( 0, 2 );

       // guardo el número siguiente, que usaré para el redondeo
    let resto = valorComoTexto.substring( 2, 3 );

       // convierto el string con los más significativos a número
    let nuevoValor = parseInt( cabeza );

       // si el tercer número es mayor que "5" agrego uno a "nuevoValor"
    if( resto > 5 ) {
        nuevoValor ++;
    }
    
       // para finalizar, multiplico "nuevoValor" por diez elevado a la longitud menos dos,
       // para agregar los ceros
    nuevoValor *= Math.pow( 10, ( longitud - 2 )); 
    return nuevoValor;
}


let valor = 19800;
console.log( redondear( valor ));

valor = 19400;
console.log( redondear( valor ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Asumiré que tus números son números enteros en milésimas. Lo podrías lograr fácilmente con una pequeña operación, veamos un ejemplo:

Tu número `19986` lo podrías dividir entre `1000`, obteniendo:

```js
19986 / 1000 = 19.986
```

Y al redondear ese resultado, con `Math.round()`, obtienes:

```js
Math.round(19.986) = 20
```

Y a ese número lo multiplicas por `1000`, obteniendo el resultado esperado:

```js
Math.round(19.986) * 1000 = 20 * 1000 = 20000
```

Que es equivalente a:

```js
Math.round(19986 / 1000) * 1000 = 20000
```

Por lo tanto, el código JavaScript sería el siguiente (con más ejemplos):

```js
function roundNumber(numero) {
  const result = Math.round(numero / 1000) * 1000;
  return result;
}

console.log(roundNumber(19986)); // 20000
console.log(roundNumber(19250)); // 19000
console.log(roundNumber(18999.999)); // 19000
console.log(roundNumber(10000)); // 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar con "math.floor()" o "math.ceil()" en tu caso usaria, math.ceil() ya que redondea para arriba

ejemplo:

```
let numero = 7.2;
let redondeado = Math.ceil(numero);
console.log(redondeado); // Resultado: 8
```

Comment: `Math.floor()` y `Math.ceil()` se usan para redondear decimales. El OP quiere redondear en miles.

Comment: Nuevamente te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.